# Parse complex multi-header html table with pandas and bs4

Tags: python, pandas, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

[Complex Table link](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerProductionType/show?name=&defaultValue=true&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&datepicker-day-offset-select-dv-date-from_input=D&dateTime.dateTime=09.08.2017%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&dateTime.endDateTime=09.08.2017%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&area.values=CTY%7C10YES-REE------0!BZN%7C10YES-REE------0&productionType.values=B01&productionType.values=B02&productionType.values=B03&productionType.values=B04&productionType.values=B05&productionType.values=B06&productionType.values=B07&productionType.values=B08&productionType.values=B09&productionType.values=B10&productionType.values=B11&productionType.values=B12&productionType.values=B13&productionType.values=B14&productionType.values=B20&productionType.values=B15&productionType.values=B16&productionType.values=B17&productionType.values=B18&productionType.values=B19&dateTime.timezone=UTC&dateTime.timezone_input=UTC)

I have used `bs4`, `pandas` and `lxml` libraries to parse the html table above but i am not having success. With `pandas` i try to skip rows and setting header to 0 however the result is a `DataFrame` highly unstructured and it also seems that some data is missing.

With the other 2 libraries i tried to use selectors and even the `xpath` from the `tbody` section but i receive a empty list in both cases.

This would be what i want to retrieve:

[image]

Can anyone give me a hand about how i can i scrape that data?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

page = urlopen('https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerProductionType/show?name=&defaultValue=true&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&datepicker-day-offset-select-dv-date-from_input=D&dateTime.dateTime=09.08.2017%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&dateTime.endDateTime=09.08.2017%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&area.values=CTY%7C10YES-REE------0!BZN%7C10YES-REE------0&productionType.values=B01&productionType.values=B02&productionType.values=B03&productionType.values=B04&productionType.values=B05&productionType.values=B06&productionType.values=B07&productionType.values=B08&productionType.values=B09&productionType.values=B10&productionType.values=B11&productionType.values=B12&productionType.values=B13&productionType.values=B14&productionType.values=B20&productionType.values=B15&productionType.values=B16&productionType.values=B17&productionType.values=B18&productionType.values=B19&dateTime.timezone=UTC&dateTime.timezone_input=UTC')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

table = soup.find('tbody')

res = []
row = []

for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        row.append(td.text)
    res.append(row)
    row = []

df = pd.DataFrame(data=res)
```

Then add column names with `df.columns` and drop empty columns.

**EDIT:** Suggest this modifed for-loop. (BillBell)

```
>>> for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
...     for td in tr.find_all('td'):
...         row.append(td.text.strip())
...     res.append(row)
...     row = []
```

- The original form of the `for` statement failed compilation.
- The original form of the the `append` left new-lines and blanks in constants.

Comment: had a typo initially, fixed now

Comment: perfect answer! Thank you!